# @groupname tag is not working with a scala class in intellij

Tags: scala

@groupname tags are not getting identified in the documentation for Scala. I am using Intellij IDE for creating the Scala doc.

Using @groupname tag on Scala objects seem to work fine but with class, I ma only finding value members not arranged in groups.

```
/**
  * A class to represent ''All Methods needed for Stdraw Tests''.
  * @groupname some_funcs Some Functions
  * @constructor Create Some Functions
*/
class xyz{
 /**
  * @group some_funcs
  */
def something() = {something}
}
```

When I run this code with Generate Scala doc, i should get something function with heading Some Functions, but I get nothing. I see only the valued members. Even tried adding "scalacOptions in (Compile,doc) := Seq("-groups", "-implicits")" in build.sbt which did nothing. Any one faced this issue.

Comment: I think compiler can't read the `@groupname`  because it is commented.

Comment: I think for Scaladoc to work we need comments right, check this link for coding style. https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/d5861aba9d80ca15ad3f22793b79822e470d6913/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.scala

Comment: Guess the problem is with Generate scala doc in intellij, when I ran it with sbt doc every thing went well.